# squeeze a webpage to show ad

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have this following jsfiddle link

where am trying to squeeze the webpage to show an AD towards right

http://jsfiddle.net/5o6ghf9d/1/

Works fine on dekstop browsers

But its not getting squeezed on ipad safari/chrome browsers

Below are functions used to squeeze/unsqueeze the web page

```
 function squeeze_page(){
    d.body.style.paddingRight='160px';
    d.body.style.paddingLeft='160px';
    d.body.style.marginLeft='-160px';
    d.body.style.overflowX='hidden !important'; 
    is_page_squeezed=true;
 }

 function unsqueeze_page(){
   d.body.style.paddingRight='';
   d.body.style.paddingLeft='';
   d.body.style.marginLeft='';
   is_page_squeezed=false;
 }
```

Let me know if any other way is there where i can squeeze the webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5o6ghf9d/2/)

If you want to have the AD slide from right when showing, it's better to use the `CSS transition` like in my example.

First, you need to have a container for the content, which in my example, I add

```
<div id="container">
    ...
    <!-- Your Content Here -->
    ...
</div>
```

to contain all your `<p>` content, then using the `CSS`, I set this

```
#test {
    position:fixed;
    width:160px;
    background:blue;
    right:-160px;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
#test.show {
    right:0;
}
```

`position:fixed;` to make it's position fixed to the viewport whenever you're scrolling it, `top` and `bottom` set to `0` to make it's height full, and the `transition` is to make it looks like slide from right to left when it shows

The same with the `div container` that's using this style

```
#container {
    margin-right:0;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}
#container.squeezed {
    margin-right:160px;
}
```

so that it looks like it's being squeezed by the AD

then use this `script` to add or remove the `class` from `#container` and `#test`

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    if (pageYOffset > 100) {
        $("#test").addClass("show");
        $("#container").addClass("squeezed");
    } else if (pageYOffset < 100) {
        $("#test").removeClass("show");
        $("#container").removeClass("squeezed");
    }    
}
```

Comment: can i add the styles of id container to <body> tag instead ?

Comment: @nyfer yes you can add the `styles` to the `<body>` if you want, just change the `#container` to `body` in the `CSS`